# Find Closed Form from Algorithm with multiple arguments

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

```
function What(n,a,total)
    if n=0 
        return total
    elseif n is even and n>0
        return What(n/2, a+1, total)
    elseif n is odd
        return What((n-1)/2, a+1, total + 2^n)
    endif
end What
```

I'm not sure how to find the closed form of this algorithm. This is not a homework question, just studying previous exams for my upcoming final. According to the marking/space given it should be a small/simple solution.

Assuming total starts at 0,

I can see that the algorithm returns 2, if n is a power of 2;
returns 2^(n/2) + 2 if n is even; and 2^n + 2 if n is odd.

For the first elseif I got T(n/2) + 1 time and for the second elseif I got T((n-1)/2) + 2^n + 1 (?) time.

Overall, I'm not sure how to go about finding a closed form here/use repeated substitution.

Comment: Are you trying to find a closed form for the algorithm's *return value*, or for its *time complexity*? It's not clear.

Comment: @user2357112 I gave an answer for running time.  I don't think I have the maths for a closed form :-)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate that the complexity of the `What()` function seems to be only dependent on the first term which is passed to it.  By inspection, it is fairly clear to see that the running time is `O(lg_2 N + 2)`, for integer `N` > 0.  To see this, just consider the number of function calls for the first few integer multiples of 2:

```
num | # function calls
 2  |         3 = lg_2(2) + 2
 4  |         4 = lg_2(4) + 2
 8  |         5 = lg_2(8) + 2
 16 |         6 = lg_2(16) + 2
```

Specifically, each call to `What(n)` will call `What(floor(n/2))`, which means that `n` is being divided in half for each linear step of the recursion.